# False equivalence or false equivalency?

Tags: phrase-usage, terminology

If you compared two objects that have a few commonalities but are essentially incomparable, would you call the comparison a **false equivalence** or a **false equivalency**? Like would you say comparing apples to oranges is an example of a false equivalence or false equivalency?
Or do they mean the same thing, and either is fine?

Answer (score 1):

The recognised term is "false equivalence".

The term applies to any assertion that two or more things are *equivalent* because they share *some* characteristics but ignores obvious differences.

"Comparing apples and oranges" is also something of an idiom. Most commonly this is used as a simile for a situation in which metrics being compared have glaring differences, so to be honest "comparing apples and oranges" is really another way of saying that a comparison is a "false equivalence".

Ignoring the idiom, it is arguable that comparing apples and oranges is a false equivalence, as they are not exactly the same, but it would depend on the comparison being made. They are both fruits, may share some similar nutritional values, and are of similar size, so there could be a number of fair comparisons drawn.

Comment: Supporting this, dictionaries give a full definition to "equivalence", and define "equivalency" as simply the first form. Google Ngram shows "equivalence" with about eleven times more use.